# Путь к файлу Servlet Java

Tags: java, файлы, servlet

Есть файл на сервере source.txt:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как узнать к нему путь и обратиться?

Comment: Путь к webapp - request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")

Comment: Смотря что за путь и с какой целью обратиться